# How to check the status code is whether 200 or not?

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

How can I check whether status code is 200 or not . I would like to do it in swift language

```
session.dataTask(with: request){(data,response,error) in

            if let  response = response {
               print(response)

             }
           }
```

Comment: Read the docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/httpurlresponse

Comment: For what it’s worth, I would _not_ check to see if the status code is 200, but rather if it is 2xx. E.g. `guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200..<300) ~= httpResponse.statusCode else { ... }`. All codes from 200 through 299 are “success” codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let statusCode: Int? = {
    if let httpUrlResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
        return httpUrlResponse.statusCode
    }
    return nil
}()
```

And then compare it to 200